# How to search for a string in workbook then write it into a column of the same row?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code seems to be skipping my second for loop. It does not give an error.

I have 20 sheets in my workbook which contains data about different products.
Each sheet contains a column by the name of "selling date" and it is on a different index number on each sheet.

On the dashboard sheet I made two text boxes and one command button.
In the first text box you enter the product number e.g. ssn-45.
In second box you enter the date on which it was sold.

When you click the command button it is supposed to find that product in whichever sheet it may be and then go to its respective selling date column and write the provided date of selling which will be in textbox2.

In each sheet the column in which the selling date has to be entered is different so I will need to write code as the for loop selects different sheets. I will tell it by if statements that if sheet is this then go to column that and etc.

The following code contains location of selling column of one sheet named SSN. I have not written code for locations of selling column from other sheets.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rw As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim y As Long
Dim msgvalue As VbMsgBoxResult

For y = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(y)
    rw = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For x = 1 To rw
        If sh.Cells(x, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value Then
            If sh.Name = "SSN" And sh.Cells(x, 12).Value = "" Then
                sh.Cells(x, 12).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
                msgvalue = msgbox(Me.TextBox1.Value & "was marked as sold on date:" & Me.TextBox2.Value, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
                Exit For
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Your logic is commendable but the second = in your for statements is an error. E.g. for X =1 to rw

Comment: let me fix that then i will let you know

Comment: You have other logic errors in your code.  I suggest you take a moment to read the help pages for For loops.  In the VBA IDE put your cursor on a keyword (in this case for) and press F1.  This will bring up the MS Help page for for loops.

Comment: i just edited it again, it goes into the second loop now. but it went past the cell that had the value i put in. and im checking all that in the debugger, line by line

Comment: please help -freeflow

Comment: Sorry. I can comment on VBA but as I don't routinely use Excel I can't comment on the code dealing with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over worksheets if you know the name of the worksheet, and Match is faster than checking row-by-row:

```vba
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet, m
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSN")
    m = Application.Match(Me.TextBox1.Value, sh.Columns("A"), 0) 'find matching row
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then                  'got a match if m is not an error value
        If sh.Cells(m, 12).Value = "" Then  'check the matched row
            sh.Cells(m, 12).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
            MsgBox Me.TextBox1.Value & " was marked as sold on date: " & Me.TextBox2.Value, _
                        vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Confirmation"
                    
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Also you don't need the result of the `MsgBox` call if you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks man you are an angel! The code looks good, i just need to add same statements for other sheets. I will let you know if it works